# How Can I use "ping command" with source?

Tags: cisco, ping, icmp

I can not use `ping 'target' source 'interface'`

```
ping 192.168.0.2 source lo0

% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.
```

It's possible if I use "ping"

```
R2#ping
Protocol [ip]: ip
Target IP address: 192.168.0.2
Repeat count [5]: 
Datagram size [100]: 
Timeout in seconds [2]: 
Extended commands [n]: y
Source address or interface: loopback0
Type of service [0]: 
Set DF bit in IP header? [no]: 
Validate reply data? [no]: 
Data pattern [0xABCD]: 
Loose, Strict, Record, Timestamp, Verbose[none]: 
Sweep range of sizes [n]: 
Type escape sequence to abort.
Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to 192.168.0.2, timeout is 2 seconds:
Packet sent with a source address of 192.168.1.1
!!!!!
Success rate is 100 percent (5/5), round-trip min/avg/max = 2/25/59 ms
```

That's time consuming! I'd like to use the "shortcut command" but I can't! Any suggestion?

My Topology, for curious
[image]

I'm trying ping 192.168.0.2 (R2) source 192.168.1.1 (Loopback0)

Comment: got no problem with that command and source interface as loopback. maybe IOS limitation. I suggest to state the IOS version. Is there loopback option as the source interface for the command in your router? If no, then it is IOS limitation.

Comment: `Version 12.4(15)T1` I can use source interface using extended ping.. Furthermore I see some video tutorials that They use it

Comment: According to the command reference, this should be available on the command line of the 12.4(15)T train as long as you are in privileged mode. Could you also provide your platform?  Maybe there is some platform specific differences?

Comment: What happens when you specify the IP address of the source interface rather than the interface name? This is how I've always used the "one line" extended ping and it's worked fine for me.

Comment: @YLearn Platform? OS? @ John Jensen using directly IP Addr I didn't test!

Comment: @ThiagoMoraes, yes, as in type of device and product line. I should have also asked about which feature license. Is this a switch or a router? If a switch, a 2950 or a 3750X? LAN base or Advanced IP Services? Sometimes the available commands and/or options is dependent on the platform and features available.

Comment: Oh This?  Packet Tracer 5.2: Router 1841

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 3):

Packet Tracer does not provide access to IOS. It provides access to an IOS-like environment that has a limited subset of IOS features/commands, mainly tailored to learn CCNA level concepts.

As such, it doesn't surprise me that you do not have this option on the command line.

Comment: Wow, this explains everything.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It is strange but in my case adding ip addressing on interface unlocked additional options in ping command

```
R2#ping ip 1.1.1.1 ?
  <cr>

R2#conf t          
Enter configuration commands, one per line.  End with CNTL/Z.

R2(config)#int fa0/0
R2(config-if)#ip address 10.0.0.2 255.0.0.0
R2(config-if)#^Z

R2#ping 10.0.0.1 ?
  data      specify data pattern
  df-bit    enable do not fragment bit in IP header
  repeat    specify repeat count
  size      specify datagram size
  source    specify source address or name
  timeout   specify timeout interval
  validate  validate reply data
```

Answer (score 0):

Source address or interface  is a partial output of the extended ping command. The interface cannot be written as lo0.

Look at this page
[Using the Extended ping and Extended traceroute Commands](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/routing-information-protocol-rip/13730-ext-ping-trace.html)

Comment: Even trying `ping 192.168.0.2 source loopback 0 or loopback0` it doesn't works!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of supplying the exit interface, use the source IP address instead.

```
ping 192.168.1.1 source 10.15.2.1 repeat 100
```

This should do what you want.

Comment: John, using R2#ping 192.168.0.2 source 192.168.1.1 repeat 100 ^ % Invalid input detected at '^' marker.]

Comment: I get the same error as Thiago. What version of IOS are you using that allows you to state "source"?

Comment: @stephenmuth, from [Cisco documentation](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/fundamentals/command/Cisco_IOS_Configuration_Fundamentals_Command_Reference/monitor_event-trace_through_Q.html#wp3309115564): *The following keywords were added in Cisco IOS Release 12.0: data, df-bit, repeat, size, source, timeout, validate.*

Comment: I've used this on NX-OS for sure, and various of versions IOS. I'll have to test a few boxes tomorrow, but I don't think I've ever had problems running the command...

Answer (score 0):

R3# *ping*

Protocol [ip]:

Target IP address: *192.168.10.3*

Repeat count [5]:

Datagram size [100]:

Timeout in seconds [2]:

Extended commands [n]: **y**

Source address or interface: *192.168.30.1*

Comment: Please consider adding some additional information to your question to make clear what exactly you're trying to explain.

Answer (score -1):

Ping has an option to allow you to use specific option source ip address to destination.

Syntax: ping -I source ip destination ip

Ex: ping -I 10.5.6.7 173.34.56.77

Comment: That's the ping binary on linux, not the ping command on cisco.